# Is there an english news corpus available to download for between 1900 and 201X (free or low cost)

Tags: english, corpora, resource-request

I'm attempting a word embedding analysis (think underlying meaning and implications, but computational) of certain keywords through time in the English language, but I am having some difficulty finding the right text to begin with.

Are there any corpora I can use for this purpose? News articles, newspapers, or anything similar are great. They key here is that I'll need corpora that span at least the majority of the 20th century. If you are aware of any collections that are longer, that would be even better.